# Calculate the difference in time in Days for Character Dates and also with Blank Spaces in one of the column

Tags: r, date

I have the following data, Both columns are dates & have to take the difference in days. However most of the values in one of date column is blank so I have to return NA for them.

a              b
02-07-2012
18-08-2012
13-08-2012
16-04-2012
26-04-2012
03-05-2012  12-05-2012

09-06-2012
30-05-2012
22-06-2012
05-07-2012
30-06-2012
09-05-2012
22-06-2012
02-07-2012
17-07-2012
17-08-2012
16-07-2012
01-08-2012
05-08-2012
17-08-2012
30-04-2012
05-07-2012
07-04-2012
27-04-2012
21-06-2012
03-07-2012
21-07-2012
24-04-2012
05-06-2012
03-07-2012
02-04-2012  01-06-2012

06-04-2012
15-04-2012
16-06-2012
01-08-2012
13-05-2012
09-07-2012
09-07-2012
18-04-2012
09-08-2012
10-04-2012
12-05-2012
04-04-2012
04-06-2012  04-06-2012

15-06-2012
02-07-2012
05-07-2012
21-08-2012
19-07-2012
06-08-2012
15-06-2012
06-04-2012
04-06-2012
23-07-2012
06-04-2012
12-04-2012  11-06-2012

24-05-2012
03-08-2012
04-05-2012  09-05-2012

07-05-2012
07-06-2012
06-07-2012
13-07-2012
26-07-2012
26-04-2012
22-06-2012
26-07-2012
12-04-2012
07-08-2012
27-06-2012
03-04-2012  02-06-2012

13-04-2012
28-07-2012
07-05-2012
29-06-2012
03-04-2012  02-06-2012

04-04-2012
04-04-2012  24-05-2012

04-04-2012
05-04-2012
07-04-2012
10-04-2012
11-04-2012
13-04-2012
13-04-2012
13-04-2012
13-04-2012
14-04-2012
14-04-2012
14-04-2012
18-04-2012
19-04-2012
21-04-2012
25-04-2012
25-04-2012
26-04-2012
26-04-2012
26-04-2012
27-04-2012
30-04-2012
04-06-2012
04-06-2012
05-06-2012
05-06-2012
05-06-2012
05-06-2012
05-06-2012  16-07-2012

06-06-2012  29-06-2012

I tried the following but couldnt succeed

```
date_strings[date_strings==""]<-NA      # Replaced blank spaces with NA & removed them
head(date_strings)
newdata<-na.omit(date_strings)
str(newdata)

newdata$a<-as.Date(newdata$a,"%m%d%y")
newdata$b<-as.Date(newdata$b,"%m%d%y")


diff_in_days = difftime(newdata$a, newdata$b, units = "days") # days
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the dates to date class which will turn blanks to `NA` automatically and then subtract days using `difftime`.

```
date_strings[] <- lapply(date_strings, as.Date, format = '%d-%m-%Y')
date_strings$diff_in_days = difftime(date_strings$b, date_strings$a,
                                      units = "days") 

date_strings
#           a          b diff_in_days
#1 2012-07-02       <NA>           NA
#2 2012-08-18       <NA>           NA
#3 2012-08-13       <NA>           NA
#4 2012-04-16       <NA>           NA
#5 2012-04-26       <NA>           NA
#6 2012-05-03 2012-05-12            9
```

Or directly subtract

```
date_strings$diff_in_days = date_strings$b -  date_strings$a
```

**data**

```
date_strings <- structure(list(a = c("02-07-2012", "18-08-2012", "13-08-2012", 
"16-04-2012", "26-04-2012", "03-05-2012"), b = c("", "", "", 
"", "", "12-05-2012")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyverse`, we can do

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
date_strings %>% 
    mutate(across(everything(), dmy)) %>%
    mutate(diff_in_days = b - a)
#           a          b diff_in_days
#1 2012-07-02       <NA>      NA days
#2 2012-08-18       <NA>      NA days
#3 2012-08-13       <NA>      NA days
#4 2012-04-16       <NA>      NA days
#5 2012-04-26       <NA>      NA days
#6 2012-05-03 2012-05-12       9 days
```

#### data

```
date_strings <- structure(list(a = c("02-07-2012", "18-08-2012", "13-08-2012", 
"16-04-2012", "26-04-2012", "03-05-2012"), b = c("", "", "", 
"", "", "12-05-2012")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```